# How to create a dinamically select based on the value selected in the first select with SQlite querying data in flask and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am not getting anywhere on this. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

I am newbie using Flask with Javascript. I have two query's in a render template to show data of two tables (the first named "modulos" and the second named "layouts") using a for loop, it works well.

But now what I want to populate layouts select with the layouts name by querying a SQLite database with the Modulos name a user selects in modulos select.

So far I have the following code:

{% extends 'base.html' %}

```
{% block contenido %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Seleccion</title>    
</head>
<body>

  <select class="browser-default"  id="modulos" name="modulos">
  {% for modulo in modulos %}
     <option class="modulos" codigo="{{ modulo['id'] }}" value="{{ modulo['id'] }}"> {{ modulo['nombre'] }} </option>>  
  {% endfor %}  
  </select>


  <select class="browser-default" id="layouts" name="layouts"  >      
    {% for layout in layouts %}    
    <option class="layouts" codigo="{{ layout['modulo_id'] }}" value="{{ layout['modulo_id'] }}">{{ layout['nombre'] }} </option>              
    {% endfor %}
  </select>



</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

And I have been trying to it with this javascript code:

I have been guiding me on this: http://myapa.es/code-snippets/selets-dependientes-javascript/

```
<script>

var id1 = document.querySelectorAll("select.modulos");

var id2 = document.querySelectorAll("select.layouts");

// Add a change event to the id1 element, associated with the change function()

if(id1.addEventListener) { // For most browsers except IE 8 and earlier

id1.addEventListener("change", cambiar);

} else if (id1.attachEvent) { // For IE 8 and earlier

id1.attachEvent("change", cambiar); // attachEvent () is the equivalent method to addEventListener ()

}

// definition of cambiar() Function
function cambiar() {

 for (var i = 0; i < id2.options.length; i++)

 if(id2.options[i].getAttribute("codigo") == id1.options[id1.selectedIndex].getAttribute("codigo")){

 id2.options[i].style.display = "block";

 }else{

 id2.options[i].style.display = "none";

 }

 id2.value = "";

 }

// call cambiar()

 cambiar();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a list of elements, not just one element!

Therefore, `id1.addEventListener` will not work! (Actually, the `addEventListener` function does not exist for arrays of DOM Elements, so your `if` block never gets executed).

So, you need to either use `id1[0].addEventListener` instead, or define `id1` to be:

```
var id1 = document.querySelectorAll("select.modulos")[0];
```

The same applies for `id2`.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I tried using this:..        
var id1 = document.querySelectorAll("select.modulos")[0];     
 
But it's not working either